# SQLite Calculating percentage with last week values

Tags: sqlite, relational-calculus

I have the following table `transactions` I need to calculate the percentage of growth for total `transaction` per day with past same day last week

A simple way for my transactions table structure

```bash
--------------------------------------
id | value | category_id | date
--------------------------------------
1  | 150   | 1           | 1632769189
```

Categories table structure

```bash
------------------------
id | name | type 
------------------------
1  | money transfer | 1
```

My current query is now getting this week ( last 7 days ) values and last week but that's not what I need, I need to get only the current week and extra column that will have the `growth percentage`

```sql
WITH week(date) AS (
  SELECT date('now', '-6 day') 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT date(date, '+1 day') 
  FROM week 
  WHERE date < date('now') 
), lastWeek(date) AS (
  SELECT date('now', '-13 day') 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT date(date, '+1 day') 
  FROM lastWeek 
  WHERE date < date('now', '-7 day') 
)
SELECT TOTAL(t.value) total, strftime('%d/%m', w.date) date, 'currentWeek' duration
FROM week w 
LEFT JOIN (transactions t INNER JOIN categories c ON t.category_id = c.id)
ON date(t.date, 'unixepoch') = w.date AND t.wallet_id = ? AND c.type = 1
GROUP BY w.date
UNION ALL
SELECT TOTAL(t.value) total, strftime('%d/%m', lw.date) date, 'lastWeek' duration
FROM lastWeek lw
LEFT JOIN (transactions t INNER JOIN categories c ON t.category_id = c.id)
ON date(t.date, 'unixepoch') = lw.date AND t.wallet_id = ? AND c.type = 1
GROUP BY lw.date
```

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: Do you need in the percentage grouth which is not total (current week vs previous one, one value) but per-day (each separate day in current week vs the day a week before, 7 separate values)?

Comment: Please construct a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk) with some sample data and your desired result!

Comment: @Akina Yes that's what I need I need the growth for example for today's transactions compared to same today but last week, I need this for the whole last 6 days and tody's